# Google scholar citation and title issues

Tags: google-scholar

**First question:** I have an important article on arXiv and I updated its title in the 2nd version. But after that Google never updated the article title and I know people are citing my 2nd version and because of this issue with Google citations are not visible. How can I force Google scholar to refresh my article list and update any possible change/citation?

**Second question:** I cited a previous work of mine in an article that is already published and Google detected it but Google didn't catch the citation. How can I make Google scholar to catch the citation?

Comment: Contact Google Scholar : they must have a help desk, we are not it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to your first question: you want to import your second version (which Scholar considers as a different paper), and then merge it with the first one.

To import the second version, on your profile page click on the squared + in the line just above your list of publications, then the new title in the search bar should get you the paper.

Once imported, tick the first and second version, and click on "merge".

Comment: I already tried it, but I couldn't find the second version of my article.

Comment: Ok, it is difficult to tell what is happening. I can suggest a hack: put the second version on another archive (e.g. Zenodo, you can do it in a few click using https://dissem.in/ ); this should trigger (or you should be able to import) this version, and citation should go to it. If the second version on the arXiv pops up, you will be able to merge it to keep your record clean.