# Google Scholar not recognizing replaced ArXiv article

Tags: citations, arxiv, google-scholar

I submitted a paper to arXiv last year and recently (within two weeks) I submitted a replacement to my article (I changed the title to match the content better and some other minor changes like citing some more papers) however Google scholar still has the older title and the citation is not updated(when I click on the title it goes to ArXiv page, where shows all the versions of the article).

I am wondering as to how long would it take for Google scholar to be updated?
I can manually change the title in Google scholar however what about the citation.

I have seen other similar posts here like

[Google scholar citation and title issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/111435/google-scholar-citation-and-title-issues)

[Updated title of arxiv not recognised by Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41412/updated-title-of-arxiv-not-recognised-by-google-scholar)

However, none of them are talking about the citations. What would happen if people cite the second version but the title is not present in Google scholar.

Comment: How long has it been since you uploaded the updated version?

Comment: Are you sure changing the title does not update the citation as well?

Comment: @cheersmate, almost 10 days

Comment: @GoodDeeds, the problem is when I go to the ArXiv page and click on version 2 and then click on Google Scholar, it says the article does not exist. The second version is a better representative however it will never be shown in Google search and hence people cannot see it (Therefore they cannot even cite it). I am not sure changing the title updates the citation but there are different ways to cite an arXiv article, they can cite  a specific version or the original version then I can merge the citations later on but for this to work both versions should exist in Google Scholar.

Comment: The three questions are actually the same.  The real answer is you cannot actually make Google Scholar do anything.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, No the question is what exactly we need to do since the paper is not even recognized by Google scholar. When you go to arXiv and then choose google scholar, then it says paper cannot be found.